# How to read .cnf file (Conjunctive Normal Form) in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, sat

The file is shown below. I need to read them and store them in a data structure(may be a adjacency list). But I don't know how to ignore the the useless annotation and begin reading after 'p cnf'.

```
c This Formula is generated by mcnf
c
c horn? no
c forced? no
c mixed sat? no
c clause length = 3
c
p cnf 20 91
4 -18 19 0
3 18 -5 0
-5 -8 -15 0
-20 7 -16 0
10 -13 -7 0
...
```

That's my code, it may only work when there's no letters in the file.

```
    // It would be the following code if the file starts with integers, but how could I change it if you were considering comments? I haven't debugged it yet so it might go wrong, I'll do it later.)

typedef struct LiteralNode {
    int linum; 
    int tag;    //When the variable is true, it is 1, else it is -1.
    struct LiteralNode *next;
} LiteralNode;

typedef struct ClauseNode {
    struct ClauseNode *next;
    int No;
    struct LiteralNode *info;
} ClauseNode;

typedef struct Clause {
    int literal_num;
    int clause_num;
    ClauseNode *root;
} Clause;
   Status CreateClause(Clause *cl, char *filename)
{
    int m, i = 0;
    ClauseNode *p, *q;
    q = (ClauseNode*)malloc(sizeof(ClauseNode));
    p = (ClauseNode*)malloc(sizeof(ClauseNode));
    LiteralNode *l1,*l2;
    p = cl -> root;
    l1 = (LiteralNode*)malloc(sizeof(LiteralNode));
    l2 = (LiteralNode*)malloc(sizeof(LiteralNode));
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &cl -> clause_num);
    fscanf(fp, "%d",&cl -> literal_num);
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &m) != EOF){
        i++;
        q -> No = i;
        q -> next = NULL;
        l1 -> linum = m;
        l1 -> next = NULL;
        q -> info = l1;
        p -> next = q;
        p = q;
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &m);
        while (m != 0) {
            l2 -> linum = m;
            l2 -> tag = 0;
            l2 -> next = NULL;
            l1 -> next = l2;
            l1 = l2;
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &m);
        }
    }
    return OK;
}
```

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JIVA.png)The image is about the data structure I use to store the CNF.

Comment: The file is not shown... and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It looks like you'll  need to: 1/ open a file, 2/ read from an opened file, 3/ tokenize and parse that input. Which of these can you do already?

Comment: I'm sorry that I made a mistake in typesetting, I'll correct it

Comment: That's OK - there are some hints on [how to ask a good question in the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please don't post images of text though - pasting the text itself is much more useful, because people can copy it to test a solution. Copying from a picture involves re-typing it all by hand, and frankly no-one will make the effort.

Comment: Anyway, just keep reading lines and discarding them until you read the `p cnf ...` line, and then start processing after that. You can't start reading in the first place after that unless you know the file offset, and it doesn't look like that will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me edit the question and anwsering. And do I have to set a pointer to the first character, and then move it backwards until the next five characters are the same as 'p cnf' ? It looks troublesome.

Comment: How are you reading the file contents in the first place? I don't know why you'd be moving pointers at all - let alone backwards - without seeing the code you're using to read the file.

Comment: I've uploaded my code. Could you please give me some advice on how to change it when you have time?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the lines: if a line begins with `c` or is empty: discard it. If it begins with `p`: parse the problem definition. If it begins with a number: switch to clause mode, and parse clauses without regard for line endings. C standard library facilitates it well.

Now, this is C, and C doesn't really come with good support for any complex data structures. Implementing data structures takes a lot of care! We'll start by implementing a "simple" dynamically-sized `Clause` type: something that, in C++, would be solved with `std::vector<ClauseLiteral>`. We need to pay lots of attention to error handling - otherwise the behavior of the program will be undefined, and we don't want that at all. We catch any arithmetic overflows ahead of time!

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int ClauseLiteral;
static const int ClauseLiteralMax = INT_MAX;

typedef struct Clause {
  size_t size;
  size_t capacity; // does not include the terminating zero
  ClauseLiteral literals[1];
};

// Maximum capacity that doesn't overflow SIZE_MAX
static inline size_t Clause_max_capacity(void) {
  return (SIZE_MAX-sizeof(Clause))/sizeof(ClauseLiteral);
}

static size_t Clause_size_for_(size_t const count_of_literals) {
  assert(count_of_literals);
  if (count_of_literals > Clause_max_capacity()) return 0;
  return sizeof(Clause) + count_of_literals*sizeof(ClauseLiteral);
}

static size_t Clause_next_capacity_(size_t const capacity) {
  assert(capacity);
  const size_t growth_factor = 2;
  if (capacity > Clause_max_capacity()/growth_factor) {
    if (capacity < Clause_max_capacity()) return Clause_max_capacity();
    return 0;
  }
  return capacity * growth_factor;
}

static Clause *new_Clause_impl_(size_t const capacity) {
  size_t const alloc_size = Clause_size_for_(capacity);
  assert(alloc_size);
  Clause *const clause = calloc(alloc_size); // is zero-terminated
  if (!clause) return NULL;
  clause->size = 0;
  clause->capacity = capacity;
  return clause;
}

Clause *new_Clause(void) { return new_Clause_impl_(4); }

void free_Clause(Clause *clause) { free(clause); }

/** Assures that the clause exists and has room for at least by items */
bool Clause_grow(Clause **const clause_ptr, size_t by) {
  assert(clause_ptr);
  if (!*clause_ptr) return (*clause_ptr = new_Clause_impl_(by));
  Clause *const clause = *clause_ptr;
  assert(clause->size <= clause->capacity);
  if (clause->size > (SIZE_MAX - by)) return false; // overflow
  if (by > Clause_max_capacity()) return false; // won't fit
  if (clause->size > (Clause_max_capacity() - by)) return false; // won't fit
  size_t const new_size = clause->size + by;
  assert(new_size <= Clause_max_capacity());
  if (new_size > clause->capacity) {
    size_t new_capacity = clause->capacity;
    while (new_capacity && new_capacity < new_size)
      new_capacity = Clause_next_capacity_(new_capacity);
    if (!new_capacity) return false;
    Clause *const new_clause = realloc(clause, Clause_size_for_(new_capacity));
    if (!new_clause) return false;
    *clause_ptr = new_clause;
  }
  *clause_ptr->literals[new_size] = 0; // zero-terminate
  return true;
}

bool Clause_push_back(Clause **clause_ptr, ClauseLiteral literal) {
  assert(clause_ptr);
  assert(literal); // zero literals are not allowed within a clause
  if (!Clause_grow(clause_ptr, 1)) return false;
  (*clause_ptr)->literals[(*clause_ptr)->size++] = literal;
  return true;
}
```

We now have a means of growing the clauses as we read them. Let's read, then!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct CNF {
  size_t variable_count;
  size_t clause_count;
  Clause *clauses[1];
};

static inline size_t CNF_max_clause_count() {
  return (SIZE_MAX-sizeof(CNF))/sizeof(Clause*);
}

static size_t CNF_size_for_(size_t const clause_count) {
  if (clause_count >= CNF_max_clause_count()) return 0;
  return sizeof(CNF) + clause_count * sizeof(Clause*);
}

static CNF *new_CNF(size_t variable_count, size_t clause_count) {
  assert(variable_count <= ClauseLiteralMax);
  size_t const cnf_size = CNF_size_fir(clause_count);
  CNF *cnf = calloc(cnf_size);
  if (!cnf) return NULL;
  cnf->variable_count = variable_count;
  cnf->clause_count = clause_count;
  return cnf;
}

static void free_CNF(CNF *const cnf) {
  if (!cnf) return;
  for (Clause **clause_ptr = &cnf->clauses[0]; *clause_ptr && clause+ptr < &cnf->clauses[clause_count]; clause_ptr++)
    free_Clause(*clause_ptr);
  free(cnf);
}

static CNF *read_p_line(FILE *file) {
  assert(file);
  size_t variable_count, clause_count;
  int match_count = fscanf(file, "p cnf %zd %zd", &variable_count, &clause_count);
  if (match_count != 2) return NULL;
  if (variable_count > ClauseLiteralMax) return NULL;
  return new_CNF(variable_count, clause_count);
}

static bool read_c_line(FILE *file) {
  assert(file);
  char c = fgetc(file);
  if (c != 'c') return false;
  while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    if (c == '\n') return true;
  return false;
}  

static bool read_clauses(FILE *file, CNF *cnf) {
  assert(file);
  if (!cnf) return false;
  size_t const variable_count = cnf->variable_count;
  for (Clause **clause_ptr = &cnf->clauses[0]; clause_ptr < &cnf->clauses[clause_count];) {
    int literal;
    int match_count = fscanf(file, "%d", &literal);
    if (match_count != 1) return false;
    if (literal == 0) {
      if (!*clause_ptr) return false; // We disallow empty clauses.
      clause_ptr++;
    } 
    else if (literal >= -variable_count && literal <= variable_count) {
      if (!Clause_push_back(clause_ptr, literal)) return false;
    }
    else return false;
  }
  return true;
}

CNF *read_CNF(FILE *file) {
  assert(file);
  CNF *cnf = NULL;
  for (;;) {
    char const c = fgetc(file);
    if (c == EOF) goto error;
    if (isspace(c)) continue; // skip leading whitespace
    if (ungetc(c, file) == EOF) goto error;
    if (c == 'p' && !(cnf = read_p_line(file))) goto error;
    else if (c == 'c' && !read_c_line(file)) goto error;
    else if (isdigit(c)) break;
    goto error;
  }
  if (!read_clauses(file, cnf)) goto error;
  return cnf;
error:
  free_CNF(cnf);
  return NULL;
}
```

As you can see, the code is far from trivial, because it's library code that needs to be resilient and not have any undefined behavior at all. "Simple" things can be quite complicated in C. That's why, hopefully, you'd rather do this work in C++ if you can.